# Convert Time String to Decimal Hours PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, format

I would like to convert time strings (Such as 2:12:0) to decimal format in hours (ex 2:12:0 would be 2.2 hours) in PHP.

Comment: John: I am fairly new to PHP and have tried to use explode into an array and my skills are just not proficient enough to understand how to program it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A fairly dumb conversion from the top of my head, using explode by colon:

```
<?php 

$hms = "2:12:0";
$decimalHours = decimalHours($hms);

function decimalHours($time)
{
    $hms = explode(":", $time);
    return ($hms[0] + ($hms[1]/60) + ($hms[2]/3600));
}

echo $decimalHours;

?>
```

Comment: Had an error in the return line (in the seconds part). It's $hms[2]/3600 and not $hms[1]/3600. Sorry.

Comment: Hi, I am getting now this warning: otice: Undefined offset: 2 in

Comment: @user727198, you can't access the third array position, because you're most likely writing  $hms = "2:12" instead of "2:12:0". This is a sample code, not taking into account if the input string is in the correct format.