# Difference between timestamps PHP decimal format

Tags: php, time, decimal, difference

Im trying to get the difference between to timestamps in PHP.

For instance I have a login time

```
  $login = "2014-11-24 13:45:00";
  $current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  // Lets pretend its 2014-11-24 14:50:00
```

I want to compare the login time with the current time, and show it in two formats

The obvious display I already have is this.  Showing the difference.

```
  01:05:00 // Time difference
```

But I also want to have this be in a decimal format for calculations.
How can I convert the above 'difference' to a decimal display.??

```
  1.083  // In this case 1:05 difference calculates to 1.083 in decimal
```

More examples...

```
 00:30:00 // half hour difference
 0.5 // Decimal

 00:45:00 // 45 minutes
 0.75 // Decimal

 03:14:00 // 3 hours 14 minutes
 3.23 // Decimal
```

Comment: What sort of calculations do you want to perform with this? Maybe your implementation of these calculations can be improved so you don't have to create separate logic to get the decimal...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595935/convert-time-string-to-decimal-hours-php

Comment: RichardBernards  the decimal is required for a spreadsheet output that is fixed and I need to provide the client as they have requested.  Otherwise I would definitely find another way to do it

Comment: Shouldn't `1:05` be converted to `1.083`?

Comment: Jonast92  Yes, you're correct

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php-on-days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $login = strtotime("2014-11-27 01:00:00");
  $current_time = time();
  echo "Difference in Hours: ". ($current_time-$login)/3600;
```

Simple :)

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/227026)**

Comment: Wow, I almost expected that to work! :)  But it returned 393632.290555561

Comment: K, nevermind, wasnt using strtotime...duh.  Thank You!